# JNI Error: Attempt to pass an instance of TangoPointCloudData to onXyzIjAvailable

Tags: android, exception, java-native-interface, google-project-tango, point-clouds

I am trying to write an application that gathers RGB and point cloud data using Google Tango Java API. So far I managed to show image from RGB camera on a screen using `TangoCameraPreview` and it seems to be working. But as soon as I point device towards a wall and it starts to capture some real depth it immediately crashes with the following exception:

```
I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnTangoEvent(void (*)(void*, const TangoEvent*), ...): Connecting callbacks...
I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnTangoEvent(void (*)(void*, const TangoEvent*), ...): Done connecting callbacks.
E/art: JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to pass an instance of com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPointCloudData as argument 1 to void com.threedvideo.threedvideograbber.MainActivity$2.onXyzIjAvailable(com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: bad arguments passed to void com.threedvideo.threedvideograbber.MainActivity$2.onXyzIjAvailable(com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData) (see above for details)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] "Binder_3" prio=5 tid=17 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x64946ba0 self=0x4ab112f8
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | sysTid=10535 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4ab11028
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | state=R schedstat=( 67362009 19616160 284 ) utm=3 stm=3 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | stack=0x4ab81000-0x4ab85000 stackSize=1016KB
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "Binder_3" prio=5 tid=17 Runnable
   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x64946ba0 self=0x4ab112f8
   | sysTid=10535 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4ab11028
   | state=R schedstat=( 67965509 19729327 285 ) utm=3 stm=3 core=1 HZ=100
   | stack=0x4ab81000-0x4ab85000 stackSize=1016KB
   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x41714b78] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x4170cc62] (libart.so)
   native: art::Runtime::Abort()+79 [0x4170d204] (libart.so)
   native: art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+507 [0x415b889c] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x415c0ad4] (libart.so)
   native: art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+51 [0x415c1254] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x41667ee2] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x41668444] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x416c6e56] (libart.so)
   native: ??? [0x415ca020] (libart.so)
   native: _JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+19 [0x489d97c8] (libtango_client_api.so)
   native: onXYZijParcelAvailable+217 [0x489d98d6] (libtango_client_api.so)
   native: TangoListener::onXYZijParcelAvailable(android::Parcel const&)+47 [0x489cf8f8] (libtango_client_api.so)
   native: Tango::ClientListener::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+261 [0x489dd0ee] (libtango_client_api.so)
   native: android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+57 [0x401dc222] (libbinder.so)
   native: android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+505 [0x401e0796] (libbinder.so)
   native: android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+37 [0x401e0b16] (libbinder.so)
   native: android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+47 [0x401e0b8c] (libbinder.so)
   native: ??? [0x401e49a8] (libbinder.so)
   native: android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+213 [0x401afa56] (libutils.so)
   native: android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+65 [0x4023ceae] (libandroid_runtime.so)
   native: ??? [0x401af588] (libutils.so)
   native: __thread_entry+72 [0x401341b0] (libc.so)
   native: pthread_create+240 [0x40134348] (libc.so)
   (no managed stack frames)
```

It seems to me like some kind of library incompatibility, but I am pretty sure that both Tango Core and Tango Java API are latest versions, all updated yesterday. What am I missing?

Here is pretty much all code of the application:

```
package com.threedvideo.threedvideograbber;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraIntrinsics;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraPreview;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoConfig;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCoordinateFramePair;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoErrorException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoEvent;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoInvalidException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoOutOfDateException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPointCloudData;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPoseData;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Tango tango;
    private TangoConfig tangoConfig;
    private TangoCameraPreview tangoCameraPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        tango = new Tango(MainActivity.this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                    try {
                        tangoConfig = setupTangoConfig(tango);
                        tango.connect(tangoConfig);

                        tangoCameraPreview = (TangoCameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.tango_camera_preview);
                        tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(tango, TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);

                        startupTango();
                    } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Tango service out of date", e);
                    } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Tango service error", e);
                    } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Tango invalid exception", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
            tangoCameraPreview.disconnectFromTangoCamera();
            tango.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private TangoConfig setupTangoConfig(Tango t) {
        TangoConfig config = t.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);

        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_AUTORECOVERY, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_HIGH_RATE_POSE, true);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_SMOOTH_POSE, true);

        return config;
    }

    private void startupTango() {
        final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE, TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
        tango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData tangoPoseData) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData tangoXyzIjData) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
                if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR)
                    tangoCameraPreview.onFrameAvailable();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTangoEvent(TangoEvent tangoEvent) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData tangoPointCloudData) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: On the face of it, it's not _your_ bug, and there is little you can do about it. Maybe, downgrade the Tango version.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks, I will try. You mean download the .jar package of previous version? There's also an option to factory reset the tablet (I guess).

Comment: I don't know what will solve your problem, but it smells like a bug in the framework. I don't think you can do much except wait for a fix, or look for an older version w/o this bug. It could be helpful to post a support request on https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/issues/86) to the same or at least very similar issue. The solution there was to add

```
config.putInt(TangoConfig.KEY_INT_DEPTH_MODE, TangoConfig.TANGO_DEPTH_MODE_POINT_CLOUD);
```

to the setup code (`setupTangoConfig()`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This seems like the solution. I will check as soon as I get to my Tango and accept your answer if it works. The error message could've been more clear though)

Comment: Strangely enough, Google does not find the answer you mentioned even if I search the exact text of an error from that post.